# For each operator in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, for-loop, foreach, thymeleaf

I can not find syntax for building simple for-each-loop in `Thymeleaf` template.
I'm not satisfied with just `th:each=""` attribute, because it copies the tag in which it's located.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
<th:foreach th:each="...">
...block to be repeated...
</th>
```

what is an analogue of `<c:forEach items="..." var="...">` or `<t:loop source="..." value="...">` in `Tapestry`. Is anything similar for that?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `th:block` as stated in the Thymeleaf guide

`th:block` is a mere attribute container that allows template developers to specify whichever attributes they want. Thymeleaf will execute these attributes and then simply make the block disappear without a trace.

So it could be useful, for example, when creating iterated tables that require more than one `<tr>` for each element:

```
<table>
   <th:block th:each="user : ${users}">
      <tr>
         <td th:text="${user.login}">...</td>
         <td th:text="${user.name}">...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" th:text="${user.address}">...</td>
      </tr>
   </th:block>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see the difference to [my implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306080/runtimeexception-memberaccess-implementation-must-be-provided) ... any idea why it' s not working for me?

Answer (score 15):

The `th:block` solution is definitely the best one, but alternatively you can also try using `th:remove="tag"` in order to remove the containing tag:

```
<table>
   <tbody th:each="user : ${users}" th:remove="tag">
      <tr>
         <td th:text="${user.login}">...</td>
         <td th:text="${user.name}">...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" th:text="${user.address}">...</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can also pass a Thymeleaf expression to `th:remove` in order to only remove the tag conditionally, e.g. if you want only some users to be included in a `<tbody>`, besides having other interesting uses.

[Here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#removing-template-fragments) is the documentation for `th:remove`.

Comment: `th:remove` is what I guessed about, but didn't tried yet :-) Thank you a lot.

Comment: @ekemchitsiga was the first one, so his answer will be accepted. And +1 to you too :)