# How to repeat each item in a DB inside an HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, thymeleaf

I've got this table where the first items are displaying ok, but on the second loop iteration the table is displaying in a wrong way:

I'm using ThymeLeaf for the front-end !

```
<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="tableHeader">Nombre</th>
        <th class="tableHeader">IP</th>
        <th class="tableHeaders">Sistema Operativo</th>
        <th class="tableHeaders">Notas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td id="datacenterName" th:each="dc : ${datacenterFisicHosts}" th:text="${dc.name}"></td>
        <td id="datacenterIp" th:each="dc : ${datacenterFisicHosts}" th:text="${dc.ip}"></td>
        <td id="datacenterOS" th:each="dc : ${datacenterFisicHosts}" th:text="${dc.operatingSystem}"></td>
        <td id="datacenterNotes" th:each="dc : ${datacenterFisicHosts}" th:text="${dc.notes}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

I want to align each item in the loops (`th:each="dc : ${datacenterFisicHosts}"`)
under the corresponding table header.

Comment: what javascript freamwork you use ? add it to the question

Comment: thymeleaf, added, thanks :)

Comment: look at this answer [th:each with table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744655/for-each-operator-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: That worked fine, thanks a lot :)