# Passing results from ServerRequest handler function to HTML/Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I decided to get into Spring-Boot and Webflux to make a web service that was on my mind for some years. I'm totally new to this, but I know some Java, so I'm playing around with some examples and got into some problems that I can't figure out.

Right now I'm trying to display the results(videoname and Link) a handler function generates to my HTML page via Thymeleaf but it wont show on the page.

### **Handeler Function**

(There is a seperate router function)

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> listVideos(ServerRequest request) {

        Flux<Path> files = fileService.getAllFiles();

        Flux<VideoDetails> videoDetailsFlux = files.map(path -> {
            VideoDetails videoDetails = new VideoDetails();
            videoDetails.setName(path.getFileName().toString());
            videoDetails.setLink(request.uri().toString() + '/' + videoDetails.getName());
            return videoDetails;
        }).filter(videoDetails -> !videoDetails.getName().startsWith(".")).doOnError(t -> {
            throw Exceptions.propagate(t);
        });

        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)       //This was APPLICATION_JSON
                .render("videos", videoDetailsFlux);

                /* 
                .cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())         
                .location(request.uri())   
                .body(videoDetailsFlux, VideoDetails.class);
                */


    }

    @Data
    private static class VideoDetails {
        private String name;
        private String link;
    }
```

This originally returned JSON. I know I would have to use Javascript to pass the JSON to the web page but I'd like to do it with thymeleaf. Unless js would be the better way to do it?

### **videos.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Stream Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 > THIS IS THE VIDEOS PAGE</h1>
</div>
<table id="allMovies" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="70%">Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="" data-th-each="video : ${VideoDetailsFlux}">
        <td>${video.name}</td>
        <td>[[${video.link}]]</td>    
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to put the method into its own controller class like this:

### **VideoController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/videos")
    public Mono<ServerResponse> listVideos(ServerRequest request, final Model model) {

    Flux<Path> files = fileService.getAllFiles();

        Flux<VideoDetails> videoDetailsFlux = files.map(path -> {
            VideoDetails videoDetails = new VideoDetails();
            videoDetails.setName(path.getFileName().toString());
            videoDetails.setLink(request.uri().toString() + '/' + videoDetails.getName());
            return videoDetails;
        }).filter(videoDetails -> !videoDetails.getName().startsWith(".")).doOnError(t -> {
            throw Exceptions.propagate(t);
        });

        IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable reactiveDataDrivenMode =
                new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(videoDetailsFlux);

        model.addAttribute("videos", reactiveDataDrivenMode);

        System.out.println("|||||||||||||||LIST_VIDEOS");

        return ServerResponse.ok().render("videos");

    }

 @Data
    private static class VideoDetails {
        private String name;
        private String link;
    }
```

### **videos.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Stream Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 > THIS IS THE VIDEOS PAGE</h1>
</div>
<table id="allMovies" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="70%">Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="" data-th-each="video : ${videos}">
        <td>${video.name}</td>
        <td>[[${video.link}]]</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But i guess I can't mix ServerRequest and Model, because I get (type=Internal Server Error, status=500) NullPointerException. 
Then I tried it as a String only method, but then I don't know how to get the uri() without "response.uri()".

Maybe someone could help me to better understand what I'm doing wrong. I probably have a general missunderstanding of how this should work.

### **EDIT:**

I got it working like this:
But I'm not sure about the selfmade BaseUri instead of a "ServerRequest request". Cold this cause any problems later on?

**VideoController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/videos")
    public String listVideos(final Model model) {

    String baseUrl = "/videos";   

    Flux<Path> files = fileService.getAllFiles();

        Flux<VideoDetails> videoDetailsFlux = files.map(path -> {
            VideoDetails videoDetails = new VideoDetails();
            videoDetails.setName(path.getFileName().toString());
            videoDetails.setLink(baseUrl + '/' + videoDetails.getName());
            return videoDetails;
        }).filter(videoDetails -> !videoDetails.getName().startsWith(".")).doOnError(t -> {
            throw Exceptions.propagate(t);
        });

        IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable reactiveDataDrivenMode =
            new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(videoDetailsFlux);

        model.addAttribute("videos", reactiveDataDrivenMode);

        System.out.println("|||||||||||||||LIST_VIDEOS");

        return "videos";

    }
```

**videos.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Stream Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 > THIS IS THE VIDEOS PAGE</h1>
</div>
<table id="allMovies" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="70%">Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="" data-th-each="video : ${videos}">
        <td>[[${video.name}]]</td>
        <a th:href=${video.link}>[[${video.link}]]</a>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont use thymeleaf but here’s an example look at the returnntype https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-webflux-thymeleaf-reactive-example/

Comment: _data-th-each=.._ !? [for-each-operator-in-thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744655/for-each-operator-in-thymeleaf#36745086)

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thats what I meant by "String only method". I got it to work like this, but  then I don't have a "request" so I had to make my own BaseUri and I'm not sure if that could lead to further complications. I will add it to the question above.

Comment: @DirkDeyne Thanks for the advice. Both works, but yours seems to be the better solution.