# make multiple select box selected with Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I’m making an application with Tymeleaf and Spring. What I want to do is make the values in multiple select box selected when the values are stored in DB.

I could achieve it with single select box by putting the same value in the th:field and th:value but couldn’t do it with multiple select box thought how to write was wrong… So please give me advise for it.

Comment: You can use th:each in thymeleaf to loop over a list of values. `https://stackoverflow.com/a/36745086/13831999`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.